# How do I use PRtools' forward feature selection in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, feature-selection, pattern-recognition

I am trying to apply a forward feature selection on a PRdataset. Following the syntax presented online though produces a bunch of errors that I don't quite understand and haven't been able to solve. Any ideas on what is causing them or how to fix?

Code used and resulting errors shown below:

```
A=prdataset(data,classes);
[w,r]=featself(A,'NN');

Error using indnn (line 50)
Trainset and testset should by identical for LOO processing

Error in fnnc (line 33)
    L = indnn(a,trainset,loo);

Error in prmap (line 231)
        [d,varargout{:}] = feval(mapp,a,b);

Error in  *  (line 14)
        d = prmap(a,b);

Error in testk (line 55)
      d = a*w;

Error in feateval (line 128)
                J = 1 - testk(a,1);

Error in featsellr>plusl (line 182)
            critval = feateval(a(:,[state.I Jsub]),crit);

Error in featsellr (line 127)
            state = plusl(a,crit,t,state,fid);

Error in featself (line 56)
  [w,r] = featsellr(a,crit,ksel,1,0,t);
```

Comment: Please list the errors